# Apply by LinkedIn Button, 400 error bad request

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to add an 'Apply by LinkedIn' button to an expressionengine site. I've created my app on LinkedIn and am using the JS SDK and have followed the guide in order to do so. My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
            api_key: MY CLIENT ID
        authorize: true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
        }

        // Handle the successful return from the API call
        function onSuccess(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

        // Handle an error response from the API call
        function onError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
        function getProfileData() {
            IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id, first-name, skills, educations, languages, twitter-accounts)")
            .result(onSuccess).error(onError);
        }
    </script>
```

I've added the button markup as suggested:

```
<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

SO the button is displayed and upon click I'm presented with my account to authorise the app, however, upon authenticating, the button disappears and I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
ObjecterrorCode: 0message: "Unknown field {_first-name} in resource {Person}"requestId: "LT59BVDVU2"status: 400timestamp: 1436259208629__proto__: Object
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use camelcasing instead of dashes:
IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id, firstName, skills, educations, languages, twitter-accounts)")